# TKinter GUI freezing with root.after

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, tkinter

I'm trying to create code to incrementally increase the voltage on a DC power supply over the span of an input duration. I've set up a GUI for doing this (it's my first try making a GUI, sorry if the code is weird), and everything works ... except that the GUI freezes while the code is executing so I can't stop the loop. I've looked into this for several hours and learned to use root.after instead of time.sleep, but it doesn't seem to have helped in the HeatLoop function. The GUI updates now, but only sporadically and there's still the "wait cursor" showing up when I mouse over the GUI. Is there some way to fix this?

I modified the code I'm using below so it should work on any computer without needing to be edited.

```
import datetime
import time
from tkinter import *

class GUIClass:


    def __init__(self, root):
        """Initialize the GUI"""

        self.root = root
        self.percent = StringVar()
        self.percent.set("00.00 %")
        self.error = StringVar()
        self.STOP = False
        self.error.set("---")
        self.currentvoltage = StringVar()
        self.currentvoltage.set("Current Voltage: 00.00 V")
        self.DT = datetime.datetime

        # Create and attach labels
        label1 = Label(root, text='Voltage')
        label2 = Label(root, text='Ramp Duration')
        label3 = Label(root, text='Percent Done: ')
        label4 = Label(root, textvariable=self.percent)
        label5 = Label(root, text="Error Message: ")
        label6 = Label(root, textvariable=self.error)
        label7 = Label(root, textvariable=self.currentvoltage)
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        label4.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
        label5.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        label6.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
        label7.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)



        # Create and attach entries
        self.voltage = Entry(root)
        self.duration = Entry(root)
        self.voltage.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.duration.grid(row=1, column=1)

        # Create, bind, and attach buttons
        HeatButton = Button(root, text='Heat')
        HeatButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.Heat)
        HeatButton.grid(row=0, column=2)

        CoolButton = Button(root, text='Cool')
        CoolButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.Heat)
        CoolButton.grid(row=1, column=2)

        StopButton = Button(root, text='Stop')
        StopButton.bind("<Button-1>", self.Stop)
        StopButton.grid(row=2, column=2)


    def HeatLoop(self, condition, TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaximumVoltage, Fraction=0):
        """Heat up the cell while the condition is true"""
        if condition:
            self.percent.set("{:2.2f}%".format(Fraction * 100))
            print(MaximumVoltage)
            self.currentvoltage.set("Current Voltage: {:2.2f} V".format(Fraction*MaximumVoltage))
            self.Update()
            CurrentTime = self.DT.now()
            ElapsedTime = (CurrentTime.second/3600 + CurrentTime.minute/60 + CurrentTime.hour
                           - TimeStart.second/3600 - TimeStart.minute/60 - TimeStart.hour)
            Fraction = ElapsedTime / TimeDuration
            print(Fraction)
            self.root.after(5000)
            self.HeatLoop(bool(not self.STOP and Fraction < 1),
                                          TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaximumVoltage, Fraction)


    # Define function to heat up cell
    def Heat(self, event):
        # Initialize Parameters
        self.STOP = False
        self.error.set("---")
        self.Update()



        # Try to get voltage and duration from the GUI
        MaxVoltage = self.voltage.get()
        TimeDuration = self.duration.get()
        try:
            MaxVoltage = float(MaxVoltage)
            try:
                TimeDuration = float(TimeDuration)
            except:
                self.error.set("Please enter a valid time duration")
                self.Update()
                self.STOP = True
        except:
            self.error.set("Please enter a valid voltage value")
            self.Update()
            self.STOP = True

        TimeStart = self.DT.now()

        self.HeatLoop(True,
                      TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaxVoltage)


    def Stop(self, event):
        self.STOP = True
        print("turned off voltage")

    def Update(self):
        self.root.update_idletasks()
        self.root.update()


root1 = Tk()
a = GUIClass(root1)
root1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`root.after(5000)` is no different than `time.sleep(5)`. It's doing exactly what you're telling it to: to freeze for five seconds.

If you want to run `self.HeatLoop` every five seconds, the way to do it is like this:

```
self.root.after(5000, self.HeatLoop, 
                bool(not self.STOP and Fraction < 1),
                TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaximumVoltage, 
                Fraction)
```

When you give two or more arguments to `after`, tkinter will add that function to a queue, and will call that function after the time has expired. This allows the event loop to continue to process events during the five second interval.

A slightly better way to write it would be to check for the condition inside the function rather than passing the condition in, so that the condition is evaluated immediately before doing the work rather than five seconds before doing the work.

For example:

```
def HeatLoop(self, TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaximumVoltage, Fraction=0):
    if self.STOP and Fraction < 0:
        return
    ...
    self.root.after(5000, self.HeatLoop, 
                    TimeStart, TimeDuration, MaximumVoltage, 
                    Fraction)
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I tried something similar, but I used the wrong syntax ... self.root.after(5000, self.HeatLoop(params)) =/= self.root.after(5000, self.HeatLoop, params).